# PHP image script not working

Tags: php

i have script for gallery. He takes image and shows it on that image url. But its not working, images wont show up on gallery pages. Everything else works. Database is okay, so are files on FTP. Any idea? Here is code of that scrip (config.php is okay too)

```
<?
require ('config.php');
$img = $_GET['img'];
if (!isset($img) or (!is_numeric($img)))
{ $masterURL = 'images/no_image.jpg'; }
else
{
$fotosql = MySQL_Query ("SELECT photo FROM photo WHERE id = '$img' LIMIT 
1"); 
$foto_file = MySQL_Result ($fotosql, 0, 'photo');
$masterURL = 'photos/$foto_file';
}

 header('content-type: image/png');
 $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermark.png');
 $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
 $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
 $image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($masterURL);
 $size = getimagesize($masterURL);
 $dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;
 $dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;
 imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, 
 $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
 imagepng($image);
 imagedestroy($image);
 imagedestroy($watermark);
 ?>
```

Comment: Mysql_Query and Mysql_Result is very outdated....

Comment: can this be a problem?

Comment: Please, change `$masterURL = 'photos/$foto_file';` into `$masterURL = "photos/$foto_file";` (double quotes) or `$masterURL = 'photos/' . $foto_file;`

Comment: still not working

Comment: I think there is something wroing with making url to html img src="", it looks like this <img src="image.php?img=872" alt="Neon Acrylic Box ">. I dont know, if i click on that there is no image.   This is php version of that img src:   echo ("<div style='text-align:center;'><img src='image.php?img=$photo' alt='$name' /></div><br />");